# How to load an xml page in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone

I'm working on a windows phone project where I have some xml files with a layout in each of them. How can I make programmatically one of them the current layout displayed in the application???? I'm working with C#. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use XamlReader Class. 
Load the xaml into that XAMLReader, it will return which ever control it is.
Bind that to the view.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I actually load it in the view?

Comment: You can bind it. For example: Put a border in your xmal. Bind the property which you have defined in viewmodel to its child.
<Border Child="{Binding Control}"/>